# Cluster bootstrapped standard errors in R for plm functions

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, statistics-bootstrap, plm

I have a fixed effects model with only few observations and would therefore like to bootstrap in order to obtain more accurate standard errors. At the same time, I assume SE to be clustered thus I would also like to correct for clustering, i.e. do a cluster bootstrap.
I found a function for lm models (`vcovBS`), however could not find anything for plm models. Does anybody know an analogous function to obtain cluster bootstrapped SE for fixed effects models?

Answer (score 1):

The clusterSEs package has an implementation of the wild cluster bootstrap for plm models: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/clusterSEs/versions/2.6.2/topics/cluster.wild.plml.

An alternative package is `fwildclusterboot`. It does not work with `plm` but with two other fixed effects regression packages, `lfe` and `fixest`, and should be significantly faster than `clusterSEs`.

With the `fixest` package, its syntax would look like this:

```
library(fixest)
library(fwildclusterboot)

# load data set voters included in fwildclusterboot
data(voters)

# estimate the regression model via feols
feols_fit <- feols(proposition_vote ~ treatment + ideology1 + log_income + Q1_immigration , data = voters)

# bootstrap inference 
boot_feols <- boottest(feols_fit, clustid = "group_id1", param = "treatment", B = 9999)

summary(boot_feols)
#> boottest.fixest(object = lm_fit, clustid = "group_id1", param = "treatment", 
#>     B = 9999)
#>  
#>  Observations: 300
#>  Bootstr. Iter: 9999
#>  Bootstr. Type: rademacher
#>  Clustering: 1-way
#>  Confidence Sets: 95%
#>  Number of Clusters: 40
#> 
#>        term estimate statistic p.value conf.low conf.high
#> 1 treatment    0.073     3.786   0.001    0.033     0.114
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately boottest does not compute standard errors. Anybody here knows a function that does compute bootstrapped SE?