# Memory efficient cluster bootstrap

Tags: r, bootstrap-4, fixest

I have a very large dataset (10m observations but reduced to 14 essential variables), and am following the following thread: [Cluster bootstrapped standard errors in R for plm functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66886282/cluster-bootstrapped-standard-errors-in-r-for-plm-functions/71064115#71064115)

My codes after loading libraries are:

```
fe_pois <- fepois(totalcountdeals ~ logdist + inst_dist_std + whited_wu_std:findev_std | iso_o_code + sic2, vcov=~pair, data = cbma, nthreads = 2)

boot_feols <- boottest(fe_pois, clustid = "pair", param = "logdist", B = 199, nthreads = 2)
```

However, this fails with large enough memory.  Any other solutions.  I need to bootstrap standard errors because one of my regressors is an estimate.

I have also tried filtering the data, and run the above on a sub-sample, just for a try.  New error there is;

```
Error in if (!is.numeric(lower) || !is.numeric(upper) || lower >= upper) stop("lower < upper  is not fulfilled") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your question!

`fwildclusterboot::boottest()` only supports estimation of OLS models, so running a Poisson regression should in fact throw an error in `boottest()`. I will have to add an error condition for that :)

The error that you observe

```
Error in if (!is.numeric(lower) || !is.numeric(upper) || lower >= upper) stop("lower < upper  is not fulfilled") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

stems from the numerical root finding procedure employed to compute confidence intervals - and I believe it is a direct result of `fwildclusterboot` not supporting Poisson regression.

The memory problems in both `boottest` and `fwildclusterboot` arise either because

- the model you are fitting is very big and fwildclusterboot only accepts one fixed effect - all other factor variables specified in `fixest` are translated to dummies, hence the design matrix passed to `boottest()` might be very large. In fact if you do not use the `fe` argument for `fwildclusterboot::boottest()`, all fixed effects specified in `feols()` will be translated to dummies and no fixed effect is outprojected within the bootstrap. You can check if this is the root of your error by running your regression via `lm()` or `glm()` (or via a similar command in Stata) and see if these estimations fail due to memory as well .
- `boottest` and `fwildclusterboot` are fully vectorized - hence both compute a weights matrix v, which is of dimension `G x B`, where G is the number of clusters and B the number of bootstrap iterations. If both G and B are large, this consumes quite a bit of memory! `Stata.boottest` has a function argument, `matsize`, that aims to help in such a situation - I quote from the documentation:
  "*matsize(#) limits the memory demand of the G × B matrix v∗ to prevent caching of virtual
  memory to disk. The limit is specified in gigabytes; e.g., matsize(8) would limit the memory
  demand to 8GB. Note that this option does not limit the actual size of v∗. Instead, it forces
  boottest to break the matrix into chunks no larger than the limit, and then create and destroy
  each chunk in turn*"

So I would suggest that you try out the `matsize` argument in `boottest` and see if your error occurs due to a large weights matrix?

Memory is a known issue for `fwildclusterboot`, and improving memory performance is work in progress.

Last, there is also a new Julia implementation of the fast wild cluster bootstrap algorithm in [WildBootTests.jl](https://github.com/droodman/WildBootTests.jl) that supports ML based models and is - in my experience - less memory demanding than `fwildclusterboot`.

**Update 1**
See also [this discussion](https://github.com/sergiocorreia/ppmlhdfe/issues/4) on using `boottest` and `pplmhdfe`.

**Update 2**
If you want to run the wild cluster bootstrap because you are afraid that the your numbers of clusters is low & your standard errors might be biased, an alternative might be to try a degrees-of-freedom correction as implemented for `glm()` in the [clubSandwich package](https://github.com/jepusto/clubSandwich). Though I have to admit that I am not sure how well the implemented corrections work for Poisson regression.